# monit, http access with four different credentials types, one using PAM

Tags: access-control, monit

monit 5.25.2

These are our credential settings:

```
set httpd port 2812
allow localhost
allow guest:guest read-only
allow @wheel
allow cleartext /opt/monit/htpasswd
```

Rationale:

- *localhost* to enable *monit status*
- *guest:guest* to enable web access, read-only, for everyone as *guest*
- *@wheel* to enable web access, full, for the local users, group *wheel*
- *cleartext* to enable web access, full, for a pair of users not on the host

I read the docs and I try to 'shuffle' the settings (sigh) but I cannot understand how to fix the usual problem: only one of this two usages is working:

- from commandline, monit status
- web access from a client pc (ip address isn't the host itself)

**UPDATE**

I stumbled upon two issues:

- allow localhost

Without it, all the clients pc can access, but *monit status* doesn't work.

Using 'allow localhost', it blocks the clients, so we have to specify also:

> allow 10.0.0.0/8

IMHO this isn't clear from the docs.

- tests from the clients pc... beware of credentials

Trying the accesses to monit from the pc, the browser caches the credentials... so these tests can be misleading.

**UPDATE**

I found the problem:

```
strace -s 512 -e connect,write /opt/monit/bin/monit status  2>&1 |more

connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(2812), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = -1 EINPROGRESS (Operation now in progress)

write(4, "POST /_status HTTP/1.0\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nCookie: securitytoken=88521284dfbc7acea0521e16e11356d1\r\nContent-Length: 58\r\n\
r\nformat=text&securitytoken=88521284dfbc7acea0521e16e11356d1", 209) = 209

write(2, "You are not authorized to access monit..."
```

Why does it send the Cookie: securitytoken= ?

In the configuration we have defined

> allow guest:guest read-only

If I make the HTTP request with the *guest* credentials, it works:

```
"GET /_status?format=text HTTP/1.0\r\nAuthorization:Basic Z3Vlc3Q6Z3Vlc3Q=\r\n\r\n"
```

Comment: I open a ticket https://bitbucket.org/tildeslash/monit/issues/769/monit-status-doesnt-work

Comment: From the server itself, this works: **curl -u guest:guest http://localhost:2812/_status?format=text**

Answer (score 0):

I open a ticket and the developers found it is a bug.

They are working on it.

https://bitbucket.org/tildeslash/monit/issues/769/monit-status-doesnt-work